# How add ScrollMagic in nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, scrollmagic

I am trying to add ScollMagic in my Nuxt project, I followed this article: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins & I've added ScrollMagic.js in nuxt.config.js and I got this issue: ReferenceError window is not defined.

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/ScrollMagic', mode: 'client' }
  ],
}

Then I've added this snippet in my component:
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
```

I still have this issue...

Even if cover it like this:

```
if (process.client) {
  Vue.use(ScrollMagic)
}
```

Comment: Read my old answer for that question, it can be helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025984/use-gsap-with-nuxtjs/54883237#54883237

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is a bit old, but maybe someone will find my sulotion helpfull.

EDIT: Also, this way you can register any plugin to nuxt :).

So what I did:

1.
`npm i scrollmagic`

2. Go to nuxt.config.js and add the following to your plugins section:

`{ src: '~/plugins/ScrollMagic.js', mode: 'client' }`

This will make sure that scrollmagic will only be included in the client. This prevents the `window undefined` error.

3. Go to the `plugins` folder, or make it in your root folder and make a new file called `ScrollMagic.js`. In here add the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import * as ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$scrollmagic', { value: ScrollMagic });
```

This snippet will make the variable $scrollmagic available in every component/page. You can call `this.$scrollmagic` to use it. For example `const controller = new this.$scrollmagic.Controller();`

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: This was the answer as was looking for. I've learned how to register plugins with those instructions. Thanks Rik.

Comment: And how about using TweenMax with this way? Or the addIndicators plugin?

Comment: @DrewBaker I've answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64090587/7847581).

Comment: @RikLamers any idea on how to add [Scroll Magic's indicator](https://scrollmagic.io/docs/debug.addIndicators.html) on top of your answer?

Comment: @Seno Well I don't have any experience with the plugin but I would assume you can import the plugin directly in the script and use it as mentioned on the docs: `var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({addIndicators: true});`.

Answer (score 2):

This is answering Drew Baker.

I think you are making it more complicated than it should be. Using GSAP with Nuxt is fairly simple.

1. `npm install gsap` in your terminal.
2. In the file you want to animate something, import gsap. In the script tag: `import { gsap } from 'gsap'`.
3. use GSAP like you're used too. `const lt = gsap.timeline();`.

**If you still want to use GSAP as I explained in the other comment:**

1. Follow the steps 1 & 2 from the other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635478/7847581).
2. In step 3 of the previous comment, create a file called 'gsap.js' in there import Vue and GSAP.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$gsap', { value: gsap });
```

Hope this helps you @Drew Baker!

Comment: Nice defineProperty syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

currently what works is to use the cdn and integrate in 'nuxt.config.js'.
Like this :

```
      head: {
...
script: [
  {
    src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js",
    async: 'async',
    ssr: false,
    defer: true,
    body: true,
  },
  {
    src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js",
    async: 'async',
    ssr: false,
    defer: true,
    body: true,
  },
] },
```

in the **component** :

```
export default {
mounted () {
  if (process.client) {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ triggerElement: '#trigger1' })

      // exemple : trigger animation by adding a css class

      .setClassToggle('#animate1', 'zap')
      .addIndicators({ name: '1 - add a class' }) // add indicators (requires plugin)
      .addTo(controller)
  }
}}
```

you can use this method for other puglins that wouldn't work on nuxt by using npm or [puglins]

Answer (score 1):

**use the cdn and integrate in 'nuxt.config.js'.**

```
script: [
  {
    src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js",
    async: 'async',
    ssr: false,
    defer: true,
    body: true,
  },
  {
    src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js",
    async: 'async',
    ssr: false,
    defer: true,
    body: true,
  },
 {
    src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js",
    async: 'async',
    ssr: false,
    defer: true,
    body: true,
  },
] },
```

**In component**

```
Anim() {
    if (process.browser && window) {
      const ScrollMagic = window.ScrollMagic;
      const bookTimeline = new TimelineMax({});
      bookTimeline
        .from(".hmbookservice-container", 0.6, {
          yPercent: 20,
          opacity: 0,
          ease: Power4.easeOut,
          clearProps: "all"
        })
        .from(
          ".hmservice-textwrap h4",
          0.6,
          {
            xPercent: 20,
            opacity: 0,
            ease: Power4.easeOut,
            clearProps: "all"
          },
          "-=.1"
        )
        .from(
          ".hmservice-btnwrap",
          0.6,
          {
            xPercent: 20,
            opacity: 0,
            ease: Power4.easeOut,
            clearProps: "all"
          },
          "-=.2"
        );

      const bookController = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
      const bookAnimScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: ".hmbookservice-container",
        reverse: false,
        offset: -200
      })
        .setTween(bookTimeline)
        .addTo(bookController);
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    if (process.browser && window) {
      this.Anim();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Vue / Nuxt projects you can use [vue-scrollmagic](https://github.com/magr0s/vue-scrollmagic) plugin.